# How to get resized image with quality as original iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepngrepresentation

I have reviewed and applied many reference to resize image with same quality but not able to get.

I am able to get image from UIView and resize with code as mentioned below: -

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData* imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    UIImage* pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pngImage, nil, nil, nil); // PNG image size: {750, 1334}
    NSLog(@"PNG Image Size: %@", pngImage);


    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(375, 667);
    [self imageWithImage1:pngImage scaledToSize:size];
    [self imageWithImage2:pngImage scaledToSize:size];

    return image;
}

- (UIImage *)imageWithImage1:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData* imageData1 =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
    UIImage* scaledImage1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(scaledImage1, nil, nil, nil); // PNG Resized image 1 size: {375, 667}
    NSLog(@"PNG Scaled Image Size: %@", scaledImage1);

    return newImage;
}

-(UIImage *)imageWithImage2:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    // Create a bitmap context.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData* imageData1 =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
    UIImage* scaledImage1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(scaledImage1, nil, nil, nil); // PNG Resized image 2 size: {375, 667}
    NSLog(@"PNG Scaled Image Size: %@", scaledImage1);

    return newImage;
}
```

PNG image size: {750, 1334}

Both image I am getting from PNG image after resizing is {375, 667}. Which is correct as per my requirement.

But the quality of both resized image is down from original PNG image. I can recognise that button, icons and texts are blurry.

How can I fix it. Please help, thanks in advance.

**I need resized image with same the quality as PNG image.**

**PNG image:**

[image]

**PNG Resized image 1:**

[image]

**PNG Resized image 2:**

[image]

Comment: it should be down you compress and resize to non retina display

Comment: when you want to display image and its size is doubled  {750, 1334} you can display by this  UIImage * img = {750, 1334}.;
img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage scale:2 orientation:img.imageOrientation];

Comment: My concern is not to display it. My requirement is to save in Camera roll with half of the original image size with same quality.

Comment: Actually I am trying to add image over video as thumbnail. My Video size is {320, 568} and image size is {750, 1334}. When I am adding it using AVFoundation then CALayer of image resizes image to the size of video. Then my image quality goes down. That's why I want to resize it firs with same quality. Then want to add at video. If you have any idea, please help.

Comment: check this https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: Thanks, I already following it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152421/discussion-between-asif-raza-and-abdelahad-darwish).

Comment: Guess what you want is something to [ImageOptim](https://github.com/ImageOptim/ImageOptim), which use various image optimization to recompress without losing quality, dont think there's already made library for that, it's open source though, you can try apply it to your project

Comment: Hay @AsifRaza how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resize with Good Quality

```
 - (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
    {
        // Create a bitmap context.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, image.scale);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it is also blurry. Not the same quality.

Comment: can't be same Quality at all